# How to handle multiple files in react and display a list of files to be uploaded

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

I am trying to figure out how to display a list of files to be uploaded. Uploading a single file is okay and I tried console.log() inside a loop and it displays all the list. However, it does not set or add into the current state which I want them to be and show on the list.

```
const Upload = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState([]);
  const uploadFileRef = useRef();

  const addFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target.files[0]) { // IF THERE ARE FILES TO BE UPLOADED
      var pendingFiles = [...file];

      // console.log(e.target.files);

      console.log(Array.from(e.target.files));

      for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
        console.log(e.target.files[i]); // DISPLAYS EACH FILE
        pendingFiles = [...file, e.target.files[i].name]; 
        setFile(pendingFiles);
      }
    }
  };

  const removeFile = (i) => {
    setFile([...file.filter((_, index) => index !== i)]);
  };

  const BrowseFile = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <label>
          Upload
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={(e) => addFile(e)}
            accept=".jpeg, .png, .jpg, .pdf"
            ref={uploadFileRef}
            multiple
          />
        </label>
        <button 
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(file);
          }}
        >
          CHECK FILES
        </button> // CHECK FILES BUTTON JUST SHOWS THE LIST OF UPLOADED FILES
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        Upload File:
      </label>
      <BrowseFile />

      <ul
        style={{ maxHeight: "20rem", minHeight: "10rem" }}
      >
        {file.map((val, index) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={index}
            >
              <div >
                <i></i> {val}
              </div>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                  removeFile(index);
                }}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Also I've noticed that I need a FileReader to read its URL in order for me to upload to the backend. Does it need to be in a loop in order to read each file in order to upload?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add them like this:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState();
if (e.targer.files[0]){
    let target = e.targer
    setImages( prevValue => ({
                ...prevValue,
                [target.name]: [target.files[0]]
                })
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the files we could define a function called `addFile` which takes an `event object` as an argument. It extracts a list of files from the `target` property of the `event object`(which are the files that were selected by the user). We can then create an empty array called `fileNames` and use a for loop to iterate through the list of files. For each file that was selected by the user, we add the file's name to the `fileNames` array. We would use the React useState hook and define a piece of state, in this case it would be:

`const [userFiles, setUserFiles] = React.useState([])`

Finally, our function calls the `setUserFiles` function and passes it the concatenation of the `userFiles` (from our state) array and the newly created `fileNames` array.

```
const addFile = (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    const fileNames = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      fileNames.push(files[i].name);
    }
    setUserFiles([...userFiles, ...fileNames]);
};
```

We can then use the `userFiles` within our JSX, we check that the `userFiles` array has any items - if it does we can loop through them and output the names of the files in the `userFiles` array. As part of your list item you can use the `removeFile` function that you already have in your code example above and pass it the `index`.

```
{userFiles.length > 0 && (
    <ul>
      {userFiles.map((val, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <span>{val}</span>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => {
                removeFile(index);
              }}
            >
              Remove
            </button>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  )}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.